# Offline data retrieval in a Cordova Windows project

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, odata, offline

I am having difficulties using the Kapsel OData plugin to retrieve data from a store when the device is offline.

Here is the situation :

- Cordova application for Windows platform
- When the app opens, I start by opening a store against my OData service (similar to the Northwind service)
- The store is created and opened. I then try and retrieve data from the store using OData.read or by setting a model and then calling read() on it.
- The store will successfully open. However, my call to read the data will succeed when the device is online, and fail when it is offline, no matter which of the two previous methods I use.

Here is my code :

```
function openStore() {   
    var properties = {  
        "name": "Emergency",  
        "host": applicationContext.registrationContext.serverHost,  
        "port": applicationContext.registrationContext.serverPort,  
        "https": applicationContext.registrationContext.https,  
        "serviceRoot": appId,    
        "definingRequests": {  
            "Products": "/Products"  
        }  
    };  
    store = sap.OData.createOfflineStore(properties);  
    store.open(openStoreSuccessCallback, errorCallback);  
}  

function openStoreSuccessCallback() { 
    sap.OData.applyHttpClient();
    retrieveWithModel();//retrieveWithOData();
}

function retrieveWithModel() {
    var uri = applicationContext.applicationEndpointURL; 
    var user = applicationContext.registrationContext.user; 
    var password = applicationContext.registrationContext.password; 
    var headers = { "X-SMP-APPCID": applicationContext.applicationConnectionId }; 
    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(uri, { 
        json: "true", 
        user: user, 
        password: password, 
        headers: headers 
    }); 

    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel); 
    oModel.read("/Products", { 
        success: function (oEvent) { 
            var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Success"); 
            msg.showAsync(); 
        }, 
        error: function (err) { 
            console.log("you have failed"); 
            var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Fail"); 
            msg.showAsync(); 
        } 
    }); 
}

function retrieveWithOData() {
    var sURL = applicationContext.applicationEndpointURL + "/Products";  
    var oHeaders = {};  
    oHeaders['Authorization'] = authStr;  
    oHeaders['X-SMP-APPCID'] = applicationContext.applicationConnectionId;  
    //oHeaders['Content-Type'] = "application/json";  
    //oHeaders['X-CSRF-Token'] = "FETCH";  
    var request = {  
        headers: oHeaders,  
        requestUri: sURL,  
        method: "GET"  
    };  
    OData.read(request,   
        function (data, response) {  
            console.log('Success');  
        },   
        function (err) {  
            console.log('Fail');  
        }  
    );
}
```

- Kapsel SDK version is 3.8.0
- SMP SDK is SP08
- Cordova version 5.3.3

I am wondering if this is an issue with the way the app is launched. I need a way to open the same instance of the application every time, so the offline store will be kept with all its data. Because Cordova-generated Visual Studio projects do not generate an .exe file (only .appx files which would need to be signed and sideloaded to be used), the way I proceed is : I run the application in online mode from Visual Studio, then pin it to the taskbar or start menu, close it and switch the device to offline mode, and reopen it from the task bar.
However, more and more it seems like this method does not work as expected.

Can anyone confirm that a Visual Studio project, opened from the taskbar, should run the same way as when it is run from VS, with the same dependencies, libraries etc? If such is the case (and I can't really imagine why it wouldn't be), does anyone have any experience with these technologies and see what a potential issue could be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution to my problem. In case anyone ever encounters the same issue, the problem was that my offline store was not being used (you can see with Fiddler that there are outbound requests to the backend system even in offline mode).

The Visual studio project does keep the store from one build or launch to the next.